# llvm-toolset-7-clang rpm installation for RHEL 7

Tags: rpm, llvm-clang, rhel7

I am trying to install postgresql12-devel-12.4-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm in my application as my driver to support SCRAM authentication but rpm requires following dependency:

```
llvm-toolset-7-clang >= 4.0.1 is needed by postgresql12-devel-12.4-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
```

Here is my application

- OS Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
- Internet Connection   NONE - not allowed as per company policy
- yum is not possible in machine
- Other links already checked but not the same scenario in with my machine. All used yum.

May I please ask anyone to point me the right direction, I also dont know If Im doing this correctly.

- Where can I download llvm-toolset-7-clang RPM file

Comment: Main question WTF postgresql-devel pulls llvm, Why do I need to install llvm toolchain to be able to use headers? Facepalm

Answer (score 2):

You can download the files from here:

centos-sclo-rh - REPO

I know that you can't use yum but I just wanetd to mention which Repo you can use.

I used a download only for it and it has a lot of dependencies:

```
devtoolset-7-binutils
devtoolset-7-gcc
devtoolset-7-gcc-c++
devtoolset-7-libstdc++-devel
devtoolset-7-runtime
llvm-toolset-7-clang-libs
llvm-toolset-7-compiler-rt
llvm-toolset-7-libomp
llvm-toolset-7-llvm-libs
llvm-toolset-7-runtime
```

The urls to download one package would be:

```
http://mirror.cj2.nl/centos/7.8.2003/sclo/x86_64/rh/
http://mirror.serverius.net/centos/7.8.2003/sclo/x86_64/rh/
http://mirror.nforce.com/pub/linux/CentOS/7.8.2003/sclo/x86_64/rh/
http://ams.edge.kernel.org/centos/7.8.2003/sclo/x86_64/rh/
http://mirror.oxilion.nl/centos/7.8.2003/sclo/x86_64/rh/
http://mirror.widexs.nl/ftp/pub/os/Linux/distr/centos/7.8.2003/sclo/x86_64/rh/
http://mirror.previder.nl/centos/7.8.2003/sclo/x86_64/rh/
http://ftp.nluug.nl/ftp/pub/os/Linux/distr/CentOS/7.8.2003/sclo/x86_64/rh/
http://mirror.ipserv.nl/centos/7.8.2003/sclo/x86_64/rh/
http://centos.mirror.transip.nl/7.8.2003/sclo/x86_64/rh/
```

One example:

http://mirror.cj2.nl/centos/7.8.2003/sclo/x86_64/rh/Packages/l/

I hope you can manage further.

Comment: Will this also work for RHEL 7? I always get search results for Centos. Thank you for the prompt reply

Comment: Yes, it's the same

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post: https://github.com/foniod/redbpf/issues/89

They install llvm-toolset-7-clang with the following commands:

```
sudo yum -y install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-scl-rh-2-3.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
sudo yum -y install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-scl-2-3.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
sudo yum -y install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/x86_64/rh/Packages/l/llvm-toolset-7-clang-4.0.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install -y llvm-toolset-7-clang
```

Comment: This worked for me on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (v7.9)